# Dreamweaver scale a page down?

Tags: dreamweaver, photoshop

In dreamweaver is there a way to scale a page down from 1000px wide to 800px without exporting new images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not. You can set the size of each image in the template, but that is more data that needs to be loaded then required. For example, you set the size to 800px, well the web browser still downloads 1000px of data (image file), this making your theme slower then it should be.

Your best bet it is resize, (and optimize) the images in Adobe Photoshop.